# How can I use grep to get all the lines that contains string1 and string2 separated by space?

Tags: linux, grep

Line1: ................. 
Line2: @hello1 @hello2 @hello3
Line3: .................
Line4: .................
Line5: @hello1 @hello4 @hello3
Line6: @hello1 @hello2 @hello3
Line7: .................

I have files that look similar in terms of lines on one of my project directories. I want to get the counts of all the lines that contain **@hello1** and **@hello2**. In this case I would get 2 as a result only for this file. However, I want to do this recursively.

Comment: I tried to use pipes with grep and wc but I could not get what I exactly wanted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any question that is "*How do I use TOOL to get RESULT*" is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Tell us what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried, but don't limit solutions by proscribing tools unless you really can't use other tools. The fact that you're asking is evidence that this might not be the best way.

Comment: Is `@hello1` always before `@hello2` on the same line?

Comment: They may not be exactly next to each other and can be in any order!

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to "do something recursively" is to use the `find` command.  If you want to find lines that have two words on them, a simple regex will do:

```
grep -lr '@hello1.*@hello2' .
```

The option `-l` instructs grep to show us only filenames rather than file content, and the option `-r` tells grep to traverse the filesystem recursively. The start of the search is the path at the end of the line.  Once you have the list of files, you can parse that list using commands run by `xargs`.

For example, this will count all the lines in files matching the pattern you specified.

```
grep -lr '@hello1.*@hello2' . | xargs -n 1 wc -l
```

This uses `xargs` to run the `wc` command on each of the files listed by `grep`.  You could probably also run this without the `-n 1`, unless you're dealing with many many thousands of files that would exceed your maximum command line length.

Or, if I'm interpreting your question correctly, the following will count just the patterns in those files.

```
grep -lr '@hello1.*@hello2' . | xargs -n 1 grep -Hc '@hello1.*@hello2'
```

This runs a similar grep to the one used to generate your recursive list of files, and presents the output with filename (`-H`) and count (`-c`).

But if you want complex rules like finding two patterns possibly on different lines in the file, then `grep` probably is not the optimal tool, unless you use multiple greps launched by `find`:

```
find /path/to/base -type f \
  -exec grep -q '@hello1' {} \; \
  -exec grep -q '@hello2' {} \; \
  -print
```

(Lines split for easier reading.)

This is somewhat costly, as `find` needs to launch up to two children for each file. So another approach would be to use awk instead:

```
find /path/to/base -type f \
  -exec awk '/@hello1/{c++} /@hello2/{c++} c==2{r=1} END{exit 1-r}' {} \; \
  -print
```

Alternately, if your shell is `bash` version 4 or above, you can avoid using `find` and use the bash option `globstar`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ awk 'FNR=1{c=0} /@hello1/{c++} /@hello2/{c++} c==2{print FILENAME;nextfile}' **/*
```

Note: none of this is tested.

Comment: The awk script is wrong as it'd report success if it found 2 occurrences of either string, not only if it found both strings, you need something like `awk '/@hello1/{x=1} /@hello2/{y=1} END{exit ((x==1) && y==1) ? 0 : 1)}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not nterested in the number of files also,
then just something along:

```
find $BASEDIRECTORY -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h PATTERN | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count lines containing `@hello1` and `@hello2` separated by space in a specific file you can:

```
$ grep -c '@hello1 @hello2' file
```

If you want to count in more than one file:

```
$ grep -c '@hello1 @hello2' file1 file2 ...
```

And if you want to get the gran total:

```
$ grep -c '@hello1 @hello2' file1 file2 ... | paste -s -d+ - | bc
```

of course you can let your shell expanding file names. So, for example:

```
$ grep -c '@hello1 @hello2' *.txt | paste -s -d+ - | bc
```

or so...

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs -1 awk '/@hello1/ && /@hello2/{c++} END{print FILENAME, c+0}'
```